# Iterm2 fully clear scrollback within ssh

Tags: ssh, terminal, scrolling, iterm2, scrollbar

I am sshing into a server from my mac on Iterm2. The commands that I run on the server produce lengthy outputs that I want to clear the scrollback before running each. So, I decided to use `clear` before my commands but it's only clearing the screen not the scrollback which means if I scroll, I'll still see the previous commands output. I used a variation of the escape characters (`printf '\e[2J\e[3J\e[H'`) but this is also not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The menu option Edit->Clear Scrollback Buffer (shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>) will clear the scrollback buffer using the mouse or keyboard.

To clear the scrollback buffer using escape codes, refer to [this page of iTerm2 special escape codes](https://iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html). The sequence "<ESC>]1337;ClearScrollback<BEL>" will clear the scrollback buffer. You can send it with a command like this:

```
printf '\e]1337;ClearScrollback\a'
```